# JS: Find a look-alike word in String and replace it

Tags: javascript, string, azure, replace

Considering the following (glytchfull) string:

```
raybradbury la foire deﬁténébres
```

After I call Azure Spellchecker API, I have potential replacements for that string. Suggestions go like this:

```
"raybradbur" should be "ray bradbury"
"deﬁténébre" should be "de ténébres"
```

As you can see, simply replacing `raybradbur` with `ray bradbury` or, `deﬁténébre` with `de ténébres` in original string would leave an extra `y` in `ray bradburyy` and an extra `s` in `de tenebress`.

Hence, I need to find a way to identify in the original string the word that looks alike the replacer returned by API and replace it fully with its replacee.

Here is what I have so far:

```
let replaceInStr = function(str, tokens, length){  
  let versions = []
  versions.push(str)
  console.log(str) // -> raybradbury la foire deﬁténébres
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    // INTELLIGENCE WARNING!
    // CONSIDER IDENIFYING THE WHOLE PART OF THE STRING THAT LOOKS
    // LIKE TOKEN NOT JUST TOKEN SO YOU CAN REPLACE IT
    let token = tokens[i]['token'],
        suggestion = tokens[i]['suggestions'][0]['suggestion'],
        regExp = new RegExp(token.trim()),
        replaced = versions[0].replace(regExp, suggestion)
    versions.pop()
    versions.push(replaced)
  };
  console.log(versions[0]) // -> ray bradburyy la foire de ténébress
  return versions[0]
};
```

Since I cannot find a generic way to do it, any feedback or different approach would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to surround your regex to match the non-space characters.

Change this line

```
regExp = new RegExp(token.trim()),
```

to

```
regExp = new RegExp( "[\\\S]*" + token.trim() + "[\\\S]*"),
```

I guess you may want to replace multiple matches at once, so add the global flag as well

```
regExp = new RegExp( "[\\\S]*" + token.trim() + "[\\\S]*", "gi"),
```

`i` is for case-insensitive match.
`g` is for matching all occurrences.

Comment: Interesting, I tried your solution and it works. I'm going to use it even I'm not sure I understand how the `[\\\S]*` flag works. Truly appreciate your help.